# Fail if SSH remote host key is unknown

Tags: ssh

I am using a tool which relies on ssh to connect to a remote host. Unfortunately this tool does not accept user inputs and when the remote host key is unknown the call hangs forever. Is there an option or a set of options which make the ssh invocation fails when the remote host key is unknown?

Answer (score 3):

Use `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=yes` for `ssh` invocation:

> If this flag is set to yes, ssh(1) will never automatically add host
>   keys to the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file, and refuses to connect to hosts
>   whose host key has changed.

The default is `ask` and this is why you have a problem:

> If this flag is set to ask (the default), new host keys will be added
>   to the user known host files only after the user has confirmed that is
>   what they really want to do, and ssh will refuse to connect to hosts
>   whose host key has changed.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can check yourself if the host is trusted:

```
$ ssh-keygen -H -F host.example.com
# Host host.example.com found: line 205 type RSA
...
```

Note that ssh-keygen exits with 0 in any case here, so you have to check the output:

```
ssh-keygen -H -F host.example.com |
   grep -q found: || echo "host is not trusted" && exit 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-oBatchMode=yes` to fail where user interaction would be required (e.g. asking for a password, checking the remote host key etc.)

Answer (score -2):

You can add default options in ~/.ssh/config such as:

```
Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

This disables ssh complaining about unknown or changed host keys.

You can limit these options to a set of host by supplying an appropriate host pattern.

Comment: This is generally bad practice wurtel as a key change may be  missed and a major  threat vector ...   ssh-add the host key or use the hostname switch when making new keys

Comment: It is the temporary solution I'm using. But it also makes ssl ignore any change of the host key. That's why I prefer a secure fail-fast solution.

Comment: @linuxdev2013 what is the hostname switch?  ssh-add is useful for passphrases but he hasn't said he uses them

Comment: This answer does not provide the solution that is asked for. It does not make ssh fail in the described situation, it makes ssh succeed, which is the direct opposite.