# How to silently discard SSH host key authentication failure dialog

Tags: ssh

We spin up new servers all the time and then SSH into those servers. We use DNSSEC and SSFHP for host key authentication. Sometimes (for whatever reason) the DNS matching will fail, which will cause this dialog to be presented:

```
The authenticity of host 'hostname.domain.com (1.2.3.4)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:obfuscated.
No matching host key fingerprint found in DNS.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

I am wanting SSH to fail silently, a return code would be fine, or at least not require interaction.

I looked through the man pages for `ssh` and `ssh_config`. I did not see anything that would cause SSH to fail non-interactively.

Quiet mode (`-q`) only 'Causes most warning and diagnostic messages to be suppressed.' It does not suppress interactive dialogs.

My main purpose for needing this is so that we can programmatically access remote servers and skip (or retry) those that are failing authentication.

Comment: This question could be similar to this one: https://superuser.com/q/908498/213787

Answer (score 0):

Use the `StrictHostKeyChecking` option; from the man page:

```
StrictHostKeyChecking

  If this flag is set to ''yes'', ssh(1) will never automatically
  add host keys to the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file, and refuses to
  connect to hosts whose host key has changed. This provides
  maximum protection against trojan horse attacks, though it can
  be annoying when the /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts file is poorly
  maintained or when connections to new hosts are frequently
  made. This option forces the user to manually add all new
  hosts. If this flag is set to ''no'', ssh will automatically add
  new host keys to the user known hosts files. If this flag is set
  to ''ask'', new host keys will be added to the user known host
  files only after the user has confirmed that is what they really
  want to do, and ssh will refuse to connect to hosts whose host
  key has changed. The host keys of known hosts will be verified
  automatically in all cases. The argument must be ''yes'',
  ''no'', or ''ask''. The default is ''ask''.
```

For example:

```
$ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=yes remote.host
No RSA host key is known for remote.host and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
$ echo $?
255
```

---

Addendum: I didn't read the question closely enough the first time and missed the fact that you are using DNS based host key checking.  I don't actually know if this will help in your case, but I'll leave the answer in case someone else finds it helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, it is not exactly what I am looking for.